# Render json in ruby rails for jquery autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, autocomplete

This is my code which render json in format `{"11":"xyz","14":"abc"}`

```
def index
    if params[:term] != nil
      @products = Hash[current_user.search(params[:term]).map{|product| [product.id,product.name]}]
      render json: @products.to_json
    end
  end
```

This is the javascript where I am updating `div #results` with autocomplete result. What I want is to make `xyz` and `abc` link with the ids associated with it but I am not able to figure out why I am losing ids all I am getting in results as `xyz` and abc`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search").autocomplete({
        //source: $('#search').data('autocomplete-source'),
        source: "entities#index",

        open: function(e, ui) {
            var list = '';
            var results = $('ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget-content a');
            var ent_id = results.html()
            results.each(function() {
                list += '<a href= '+$(this).html()+'/'+ent_id+ '>' +$(this).html()+'</a>'+ '<br />';
            });
            $('#results').html(list);
        }
    })
} )
```

Right now above javascript code is not working as required because i am not able to get ids.

Thanks

Comment: which autocomplete jquery plugin is this? there are many

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

I found a soulution for it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#search" ).autocomplete(
        {
            source:"entities#index",
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#search" ).val( ui.item[1] );
                $( "#results").empty();
                $( "#results" ).append( '<a href= '+"entities"+'/'+ui.item[0]+ '>' +ui.item[1]+'</a>' );
                return false;
            }

        }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item[1] + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };

} )
```